# と usage with いる and the っちゃう ending on a verb

Tags: particle-こと

total Japanese noob here. Recently I got the manga しろくまカフェ and I started working through it.
Within the first few sentences I'm stumped:

> でも寝てばっかりいる太っちゃう〜

I got the gist of the sentence "Just sleep here and I will get fat", but I don't understand a few parts and I don't think my translation is very good. I don't really understand the combination of いる(to exist) and と(my understanding of と was with or and only with nouns). Additionally, I've never seen the っちゃう ending on the verb 太る(to get fat) before. Why wouldn't it just be, well, 太る?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> でも寝てばっかりいる**と**太っちゃう〜

From your description, I'm guessing there's a と here?

If that's the case, と is used to mean that the following clause is the result of the clause before it. AとB means that, If A happens, B occurs. So here, it means that "**If** I just lay around all day, I'll get fat".

> 寝てばっかりいる

This comes from the structure て-form verb + ば（っ）かり+いる. If you read grammar about ばかり,they'll tell you that this is quite a common way to use this grammar. It means that you are doing an action "all the time" or "only doing".

> 太っちゃう

This is the casual form of Verb + てしまう. It means to do something unintentionally. It has other meanings as well, such as causing an unintended effect, or doing something to completion. 太ってしまう would mean "to get fat", but implies that this is unintentional or an unwanted effect. You don't want to get fat, but you got fat.

I hope this helps! It seems like you're missing a lot of grammar points simply because you haven't gotten far enough yet. I think you should maybe read a bit more on grammar so you don't get as confused.

Comment: Thank you, SO MUCH! I know it's been awhile since you answered, but thanks! I have a few beginner grammar workbooks I'm working through at the moment :)